Assistance with where to paste my API key code and the JSON file text
I am setting up my credentials for the Google Translator. This is my first project here. Working with instructions from AI Content Lab on how to do so. I now have my JSON key code translated to text but where do i paste this text? Also, I searched around on Google Cloud and created an API Key within my service account project, and it gives a link to copy the key but where do i paste or copy that to? On the instructions from AI Content Labs, it states to enter the API key within AI Content Labs but upon logging in it requests me to subscribe for $9/mo. Can someone assist with the steps i need to take to get set up to use my services as a Google Translator?
